# How to simulate network from tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I have a code of convolutional network from tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import input_data

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(100):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print "step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy)
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print "test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
```

How can I simulate this network? That is, I want to get a network's answer on the particular image from `mnist.test.images`. Something like that:

```
print simulate(network, mnist.test.images[0])
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In tensor flow every node in the graph can be evaluated. So, similarly to how you evaluate the `accuracy`, you can also evaluate any other node in the graph. The entire neural network is represented by its last layer, in your case `y_conv`. I don't have TensorFlow handy, but something along the lines of the following line should work:

```
y_conv.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0]})
```